# Alpha Vantage passing multiple queries - Global Quote

Tags: python, python-3.x, alpha-vantage

I am trying to pass values from an Alpha Vantage query into a pandas df so that I can extract certain values.

When I run a simple, 1 symbol query, I can easily pass the information into a df. After that, I can transpose the df and extract the data using the columns.

An example is:

```py
import requests
import alpha_vantage
import pandas as pd

API_URL = "https://www.alphavantage.co/query"
data = {
    "function": "GLOBAL_QUOTE",
    "symbol": "MSFT",
    "apikey": "XXX",
    }

response = requests.get(API_URL, params=data)
print(response.json())

df = pd.DataFrame(response.json())
df = df.T
print()
print()
print(df)
```

This returns:

[image]

However, I am looking to pass multiple symbols, I keep getting an error saying:

> {'Error Message': 'Invalid API call. Please retry or visit the documentation (https://www.alphavantage.co/documentation/) for GLOBAL_QUOTE.'}

The code being used is:

```py
import requests
import alpha_vantage
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()
API_URL = "https://www.alphavantage.co/query"

symbols= ["IBM", "MSFT", "APPL"]
for symbol in symbols:
    data = {
        "function": "GLOBAL_QUOTE",
        "symbol": symbols,
        "apikey": "XXX",
        }

    response = requests.get(API_URL, params=data)

    print(response.json())
```

I believe that corresponds to the format that is expected from the website:

> https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=GLOBAL_QUOTE&symbol=MSFT&apikey=demo

My question is: How can I pass multiple requests to the Alpha Vantage API using a list of symbols?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change "symbols" to "symbol"

`"symbol": symbols,` -> `"symbol": symbol,`
Right now you're passing the entire list as data.

```
import alpha_vantage
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()
API_URL = "https://www.alphavantage.co/query"

symbols= ["IBM", "MSFT", "APPL"]
for symbol in symbols:
    data = {
        "function": "GLOBAL_QUOTE",
        "symbol": symbol,
        "apikey": "XXX",
        }

    response = requests.get(API_URL, params=data)

    print(response.json())
```

Comment: These are still multiple requests, not one.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use BATCH_STOCK_QUOTES and use a string instead of an array, and that should do it:

```
import requests
import alpha_vantage
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()
API_URL = "https://www.alphavantage.co/query"

#symbols= ["IBM", "MSFT", "LVLT"]
symbols= "IBM,MSFT,LVLT"
data = {
        "function": "BATCH_STOCK_QUOTES",
        "symbols": symbols,
        "apikey": "XXX",
        }

response = requests.get(API_URL, params=data)


print(response.json())
```

http://alpha.vantage.api.gallery.streamdata.io/listings/alpha-vantage/queryfunctionbatch-stock-quotes-get-openapi/

Comment: Looks like this method has been discontinued. Additionally, it provided less information than I needed.